# AWS Parameters Store get all keys and values

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

I am writing a "PropertiesManager" that needs to refresh the values every X minutes.  We are using AWS Parameter Store and I would like to get all the key/values starting with "blah".  I see I can get the metadata in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872861/aws-ssm-parameter-store-not-fetching-all-key-values) but was hoping not to have to get the metadata and then go back for the values.

It would be very close to this but actually get the values.  Also, how do I set up the request?:

```
 DescribeParametersRequest request = new DescribeParametersRequest();
  DescribeParametersResult response;
  do
  {
    response = ssm.describeParameters(request);
    for (ParameterMetadata param : response.getParameters())
    {
      // param does not have the value!
    }
    request.setNextToken(response.getNextToken());
  }
  while ((response.getNextToken() != null) && ! respose.getNextToken.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetParametersByPath()`, which will return all parameters with a given path prefix.

So, you could create a prefix like `/Finance/Prod/IAD/WinServ2016/license33` and you could ask for all parameters under a given path, such as `/Finance/Prod/IAD/`.

Comment: Sweet!  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!