# Accessing Amazon Global Infrastructure region table (for RestAPI or dotNet)

Tags: amazon-web-services

When the user selects an Amazon service (s3,CloudFront, etc) from a drop-down menu, I'd like to show only those regions/locations available for the selected service.

How can I determine this information? Is there a way to query Amazon's [Global Infrastructure region table](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) using RestAPI or dotNet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Systems Manager can help with this. It has SDKs for various languages as well as a rest API.

For example, to get all the regions for the AWS Athena You can use [GetParametersByPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersByPath.html)
with the path   `/aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/athena/regions`

Answer (score 1):

After answer by @adi-dembak, Here are my steps to achieve this task in .net

Add following [SSM Managed Policy](https://github.com/aws/aws-ssm-data-protection-provider-for-aspnet/blob/master/README.md#permissions) in aws and assign policy to user.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "rule1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:PutParameter",
            "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]}
```

Install AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement

```
        string accessKey = "123##";
        string secretKey = "321##";

        HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>();

        AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient amazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient =
            new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        GetParametersByPathRequest getParametersByPathRequest = new GetParametersByPathRequest();
        getParametersByPathRequest.Path = "/aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/s3/regions/";
        getParametersByPathRequest.Recursive = true;

        GetParametersByPathResponse getParametersByPathResponse;

        do
        {
            getParametersByPathResponse = await amazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient.GetParametersByPathAsync(getParametersByPathRequest);
            foreach (Parameter item in getParametersByPathResponse.Parameters)
            {
                hash.Add(item.Value);

            }
            getParametersByPathRequest.NextToken = getParametersByPathResponse.NextToken;
        }
        while ((getParametersByPathResponse.NextToken != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(getParametersByPathResponse.NextToken.ToString()));

        //Print HashSet
        foreach (string item in hash)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

[GetParametersByPath is a paged operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872861/aws-ssm-parameter-store-not-fetching-all-key-values/52876155). After each call you must retrieve NextToken from the result object, and if it's not null and not empty you must make another call with it added to the request.